# Improved Banking Security

Tags: dual-boot

I am looking at ways to tighten my PC or Mac security with regard to banking and other financial activities.

One solution is to have a device (laptop, PC) that is used exclusively for those activities (no other internet activity) and the device is turned off when not in use.

However it occurred to me that booting to Ubuntu from a USB drive and then using the USB stick exclusively for banking/finance may offer a great security solution for very little cost.

It seems to me that the same isolation security may hold true when booting Ubuntu from Virtualbox - although the PC would not be turned off in a dual boot situation the operating systems would be isolated.

Where are the holes in my thinking?

What are some other ideas for keeping today's very sophisticated cyber-criminals at bay.

Thank you for any feedback you may provide.
Cheers

Comment: You can boot the ubuntu iso (you can even make it read-only) in virtualbox. this will have the same effect than booting your Pc with Live USB.

Answer (score 2):

Banking security is pretty sophisticated. Most of the available holes are on your end. For instance, storing your passwords for your banking site on your system is likely a bad idea unless you keep your computer in a vault. You might want to avoid banking over wireless (**especially public wifi which isn't typically encrypted to the level available on  private wifi**) to avoid broadcasting encrypted data (which could possibly be decrypted). I would consider the combination of login and security questions along with the other security features (which differ slightly from bank to bank) to be sufficient.

Comment: You may want to rephrase "over wireless" to "over unsecured wireless" - there's encryption within protected wifi networks to limit interception of data, but on public wifi it's easily intercepted.

Answer (score 1):

Does your bank not have two-factor authentication?  Most nowadays have a keypad you need a code from to access the banking. Other than that, man in the middle attacks are the main concern as far as I see it.

Comment: "Do you not have duel security? Most nowadays have a keypad you need a code from to access the banking."  <-- Which banks have this? Currently, you're essentially switching ATMs/credit card processing systems with 2Factor Authentication, of which only a handful of banks implement currently.

Comment: @ThomasW. I have 4.bank accounts one with barclays, Natwest,  lloyds and Santander all with 2 factor authentication.

Comment: I only bank from PC that is connected via Ethernet cable (never use WiFi banking period), I am loaded with protection software and use Firefox with security add-ons. I never click on any email links or fall for phishing hooks.  based on my reading it appears that state backed cyber criminal (Russians, east Europeans, etc.) are winning the security wars and I was simply looking to isolated banking and other financial transactions so as to limit exposure. -- I appreciate the sharing of thought. Cheers